# NextAuth.js: My Pages URL Overrides My Callback Redirect - How to Fix?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using NextAuth.js in my Next.js application and facing an issue where the URL specified in the pages configuration is overriding the custom redirect logic I've implemented in a callback. Here's what my configuration looks like:

```
pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
    error: '/login', // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    verifyRequest: '/email-validate', // Used for check email page
  },
 async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      // Allows relative callback URLs
      if (url.startsWith('/')) {
        return `${baseUrl}${url}`;
      }
      // Allows callback URLs on the same origin
      else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) {
        return url;
      }
      return baseUrl;
    },
```

What I Tried:
I implemented a custom redirect logic using NextAuth.js in my Next.js application. I specified custom logic in a callback to handle redirects and defined specific pages for sign-in and error in the pages configuration. I was attempting to redirect users based on their previous path or a default URL, with specific logic for handling cases where the user came from a registration page.

What I Expected:
I expected the custom redirect logic in the callback to handle the redirection based on my conditions. If a user was previously on the registration page and an error occurred during the sign-in process with a Single Sign-On (SSO) provider, I wanted them to be redirected back to the registration page.

What Actually Resulted:
Despite my custom logic, the application always redirects to the /login page, as specified in the pages configuration. The URL specified in the pages seems to override my custom logic in the callback, and I'm unable to achieve the desired redirect behavior.

I've looked into the NextAuth.js documentation and tried various configurations, but I'm still facing this issue. I'm seeking guidance on how to make the custom redirect logic take precedence over the URL specified in the pages configuration or any alternative solutions that would allow me to achieve the desired redirect behavior.